# MAC El Capitan- Need to install 1.7 JVM even if 1.8 is available

Tags: java, macos, java-8, osx-elcapitan

> MAC El Capitan

When I am installing my application (which requires java 1.7 and above) then I got following message

> You need at least a 1.7 Java Virtual Machine to install Inmarsat LaunchPad Installer.
>   Please download it from http://www.apple.com
>
> **s5tes155cbc038:~ ABC$ java -version**
>
> java version "1.8.0_91"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Then why it is asking for 1.7 to install? Is it anything related to 32bit /64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever developed that application has yet to update his code for java 1.8. The code may contain features removed by 1.8 or something else.  You could wait for an update to the program. I hope this was informative